# Image crop position with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, python-3.x, canvas, crop

I have an image which is 640px by 480px and I have coordinates where I want to create a canvas crop of the image. I am a bit confused as to how to work out for 1, the crop size, where to crop and so on.

How would one work out the correct position to crop and the crop size? e.g. what size to set the canvas from coordinates such as the following

```
coordinates = [160, 593, 345, 407] // [top, right, bottom, left]
```

essentially im returning image coordinates from a Python script but no idea how to work out the correct positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawImage() method takes arguments for source and destination coordinates.

```
 context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up getting my head around the width and height of the crop returned this helped